# Parallel Copy from local folders to remote servers at the same time

Tags: rsync, gnu-parallel, pscp

I have a multiple folders, and each folder has about 1500 files. I have a kind of for loop going over each folder and then sending the files to either one or 4 remote hosts depending upon the environment. Currently I am using `rdist`.
Almost every file I have is changing on a daily basis, sometimes it just changes the date and time inside the file.

I came across few commands like `pscp`, `prsync` as well as GNU `parallel`. I experimented with `pscp` and `rdist` on multiple hosts, both are giving similar results.

1. What is the difference between `rdist` and `prsync` in terms of performance? My understanding is that `prsync` can migrate files on multiple hosts and same is with `rdist`. My understanding from my tests is that neither `prsync` nor `rdist` copy multiple files in parallel on single host; they can only copy file by file in parallel on multiple hosts in parallel. So is there any difference between the two from performance side?

   For `rdist`, my scripts create a distfile like

   ```
   HOSTS( user@server user@server2 user@server3 )
   RUN:(/var/inputpath/folder)
   -> ${HOSTS}
   install (/var/outputpath/folder)
   ```

   then I run `rdist` like following

   ```
   rdist-f /dist-file-path -P /path/to/ssh
   ```
2. I tested GNU `parallel` for local copy using `cp` and zipping using `zip`. It is really very fast. This allows copying multiple files in parallel even on local computer.

So my question is, is there a possibility to combine GNU parallel with say `pscp` or `rdist` or `prsync`?

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` is excellent at syncing 2 dirs if there are few changes. It can even compress the datastream using `-z`.

Unfortunately `rsync` is very dependent on latency, so it will often not be able to fill a large connection (e.g. 1 Gbps).

This can be mitigated by running multiple `rsync`s in parallel.

From `man parallel`:

> **EXAMPLE: Parallelizing rsync**
>
> rsync is a great tool, but sometimes it will not fill up the available bandwidth. This is often a problem when
>   copying several big files over high speed connections.
>   The following will start one rsync per big file in src-dir to dest-dir on the server fooserver:
>
> ```
> cd src-dir; find . -type f -size +100000 | \
>   parallel -v ssh fooserver mkdir -p /dest-dir/{//}\; \
>   rsync -s -Havessh {} fooserver:/dest-dir/{}
> ```
>
> The dirs created may end up with wrong permissions and smaller files are not being transferred. To fix
>   those run rsync a final time:
>
> ```
> rsync -Havessh src-dir/ fooserver:/dest-dir/
> ```

If your files are small you can do something like:

```
find ... |
  parallel -j10 -X rsync -zR -Ha ./{} fooserver:/dest-dir/
```

Adjust `-j10` until you find the optimal number.

The `./{}` is needed to make `rsync -R` take effect and thus copy the directory structure and not just copy all files into a single dir.